# Realizar a soma de um campo somado - PL/SQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, pl-sql

Preciso realizar a soma de um campo ao qual foi realizado uma soma conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM

     (SELECT DTAGENDA, AG.CODITPROD, CD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AG.CODITPROD, CD ORDER BY DTAGENDA) AS RANK,
      sum(QTAGENDA) QTD_AGENDA
      FROM ADM.MAG_T_DW_AGENDAMENTO AG
      INNER JOIN ADM.MAG_T_ARVORE_PRODUTO A ON A.CODITPROD = AG.CODITPROD
      WHERE AG.DTAGENDA >= TO_DATE(SYSDATE)  and AG.DTAGENDA <= TO_DATE(SYSDATE+180)
      AND AG.STATUS NOT IN ('CANCELADO', 'DEVOLVEU POR DIVERGÊNCIA', 'NÃO COMPARECEU', 'DESISTÊNCIA')
      GROUP BY DTAGENDA, AG.CODITPROD, CD
      ORDER BY AG.CODITPROD, CD, DTAGENDA) A,

                   (SELECT SUM(QTAGENDA) AS AGENDA_30
                    FROM ADM.MAG_T_DW_AGENDAMENTO AG
                    INNER JOIN ADM.MAG_T_ARVORE_PRODUTO A ON A.CODITPROD = AG.CODITPROD
                    WHERE DTAGENDA >= TO_DATE(SYSDATE+30)
                    GROUP BY AG.CODITPROD
                    ) B              
WHERE A.RANK = 1
```

Porem, o resultado obtido da segunda subselect esta longe do esperado, conforme imagem abaixo.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/guSf2.png

O cenário esperado seria uma soma do campo A.QTD_AGENDA, porem não conheço uma sintax que permita o mesmo.

OBS: ROLLUP não ajudaria

Comment: coloque a estrutura das tabelas e um SQL Fiddle para ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentou :

```
SELECT A FROM

     (SELECT DTAGENDA, AG.CODITPROD, CD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AG.CODITPROD, CD ORDER BY DTAGENDA) AS RANK,
      sum(QTAGENDA) QTD_AGENDA,
      SUM(QTAGENDA) OVER(PARTITION BY AG.CODITPROD, CD ORDER BY DTAGENDA) AS AGENDA_30
      FROM ADM.MAG_T_DW_AGENDAMENTO AG
      INNER JOIN ADM.MAG_T_ARVORE_PRODUTO A ON A.CODITPROD = AG.CODITPROD
      WHERE AG.DTAGENDA >= TO_DATE(SYSDATE)  and AG.DTAGENDA <= TO_DATE(SYSDATE+180)
      AND AG.STATUS NOT IN ('CANCELADO', 'DEVOLVEU POR DIVERGÊNCIA', 'NÃO COMPARECEU', 'DESISTÊNCIA')
      GROUP BY DTAGENDA, AG.CODITPROD, CD
      ORDER BY AG.CODITPROD, CD, DTAGENDA) A
WHERE A.RANK = 1
```